# now my code throws out another TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working on the Python implementation of Wheel of fortune for some time now, and I was just testing out the code and it threw out another TypeError. The code is here:
https://gist.github.com/HarrySlaughter/ea58b537f3ada041953cf6119bb0a754

and here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    wheel_of_fortune()
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 53, in wheel_of_fortune
    player1firstturn(player1name, player2name, player3name, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, 0, 0, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 187, in player1firstturn
    player1do(prize, choice, player1name, player2name, player3name, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 229, in player1do
    player1firstturn(player1name, player2name, player3name, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 167, in player1firstturn
    player2firstturn(player1name, player2name, player3name, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 436, in player2firstturn
    player2do(prize, choice, player1name, player2name, player3name, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
TypeError: player2do() takes 13 positional arguments but 14 were given
```

can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: in line 436 while calling function player2do(prize, choice, player1name, player2name, player3name, text, blank_text, letters, consonants, vowels, vwit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount) you gave 14 positional arguements but your function player2do() takes only 13. you gave 1 extra argument to this function. check for it.

Comment: Please don't link the code on git-hub, or anywhere else for that matter. Please copy and paste your code into your post